Does increased thermal emissivity decrease the effectiveness of a solar sail?
I am aware that increased emissivity in solar sails aids with heat reduction, however, I have done some research and found that the emissivity decreases the trajectory of the solar sail through the negative force. The research I have completed has denoted that the aluminum side of the solar sail (the reflective side) has a high solar and thermal reflectivity, a low thermal emissivity and low solar absorption. However, the Chromium/CP1 polyimide/Polyethylene terephthalate (PET) side of the sail has values closer to the middle ground for the above thermo-optical factors.
I would like to know 2 things:

Does a higher thermal emissivity on the Cr/CP1/PET side decrease the speed of the solar sail as there is a negative force applied?
How does the high solar and thermal reflectivity from the Cr/CP1/PET affect the speed of the sail?
How does the solar absorption of the Cr/CP1/PET affect the speed of the sail?


I would expect this to be a fairly straightforward yes

Hi Holly -welcome to Space Stack Exchange. Can you please edit your post to just focus on one question (not the 2 or 3 you have at the moment) as that is one of our requirements. See our [ask] page.

There are two concepts that are very important here 1) optical properties at thermal infrared wavelengths (cooling) vs those at visible wavelengths (solar sailing) and 2) front side (propulsive surface facing Sun) vs back side (radiating surface facing away from Sun) It's necessary to break the problem down this way before one can do any real engineering analysis or design optimization.

Welcome to space stackexchange. I suggest concentrating on your Q1. If this helps find your way through the terminology: at any given wavelength the reflectance = 1- absorptance and also absorptivity = emissivity, thus once you have found an answer to your Q1 the others will be related at thermal wavelengths. That leaves solar wavelengths as a separate question. You might find some of the solar wavelength part answered here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail
